# Find student id with highest marks using INNER JOIN and EXCEPT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table, find the highest marks using INNER JOIN and EXCEPT. It straight forward find marks. `Select max(marks) from Students`. But how to find highest using `INNER JOIN` and `EXCEPT`?

**Students Table**

| sno | name | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 90 |
| 2 | B | 95 |
| 3 | C | 96 |
| 4 | D | 82 |
| 5 | E | 87 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write an `INNER JOIN` or `EXCEPT` (your question is tagged mysql which doesn't support the `EXCEPT` statement) to get the student id with the highest mark. It's much simpler to write:

```
select sno from students
where marks = (select max(marks) from students)
```

Result:

```
3
```

If you use an INNER JOIN you just complicate things and essentially do the same. Example:

```
select s1.sno, s1.marks from students s1
inner join (select max(marks) as max_mark from students) s2
on s1.marks = s2.max_mark
```